# Should I use fontawesome-free or angular-fontawesome

Tags: css, angular, svg, font-awesome, webfonts

We are starting an Angular 6 project and want to use Font Awesome 5.1. Font Awesome provides two Node packages:

- `@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome` - uses SVG with JS
- `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free` - uses Web Fonts with CSS

Using **SVG with JS** is the new way to use Font Awesome while **Web Fonts and CSS** is the more classic approach. For me it seems it is a bit more hassle to use SVG with JS because you have to `import` each icon, but it saves file size.

We are going to be using around 30 icons in our app and are wondering which approach would be better for us.

Comment: To the people voting to close this as "Primarily Opinion Based": Is there really _no_ facts that can be used to help someone pick between SVG and web fonts? Is using web fonts and CSS _really_ just as good in *every* situation with no corner cases? If that's the case, I'd value an answer defending that position.

Answer (score 18):

I've just wondered the same thing, so even though it's opinion based (and thus subject to closure), I'll answer you :

I started by using the library as [described in their guide](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular).

I quickly realized you could **NOT** use all the icons you wanted, because there is no way in using `fas` or `far` icons.

So I switched to the "old" way : I installed the library with

```
npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

and imported it in my `angular.json` file :

```
projects -> yourProject -> architect -> build -> styles : {
  "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
}
```

I now have to use the usual way with

```
<i class="fab fa-accessible-icon"></i>
```

But i can use all the icons provided instead of only a single set.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but I think that `far` icons are PRO features, and need a paid licence, that's why you could not use them. `fas` is the default free version (same as `fa`)

Comment: Well you're probably wrong, because I used them without paying with the "old way", but since I'm no font awesome pro, I can't be sure I'm not wrong either !

Comment: Presuming you won't be modifying it directly, I would recommend using the smaller minified version (`all.min.css`) in your `angular.json`, instead of the `all.css`.

Answer (score 9):

Some other considerations:

1. `angular-fontawesome` integrates tightly with the Angular framework, so if you think you may want to have some data bound icons (eg: email icon with a counter of unread messages, or some icon with a rotation angle bound to some data value in your model), then you may find it nice to use `angular-fontawesome` where the icon is not only rendered as an SVG, it's rendered as an Angular component.
2. The SVG method of Font Awesome 5 is capable of some features that are not available with the Web Fonts and CSS method. For example, [Power Transforms](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/power-transforms), [Layers, and Counters](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/layering). Since `angular-fontawesome` builds on the SVG with JavaScript implementation, it supports all of those extra features too.
3. Tree-shaking / subsetting: There are many, many icons that you won't be using. If you care about optimizing the size of your downloaded assets in your production builds, then you might want to make sure you're using tree-shaking, which you'll get [mostly automagically](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/other/tree-shaking) if you use `angular-cli` (Caveat: see that link about configuring your build to work around a build performance regression that makes Webpack 4 production builds slow until the fix is released.)

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular Font Awesome as it's work as an Angular component. Also Rendered as SVG so help in data-bound logics.